# Materialized View with Inner Join says "Unsupported operator in materialized view: Join"

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, materialized-views

[BigQuery now has materialized views using inner join in Preview.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#inner_joins)

Do I have to do something special to enable this feature?

The following query throws
`Unsupported operator in materialized view: Join`

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
  views.output_mv AS
SELECT
  full_data.*
FROM
  `project.data.full_data` full_data
INNER JOIN 
  `project.scheduled.max_dates` max_dates
ON
  max_dates.max_date = full_data.date_of_data
  AND max_dates.id = full_data.id
```

`project.data.full_data` is a native table

`project.scheduled.max_dates` is a scheduled table (once per hour) based on `project.data.full_data`

Comment: I see in the documentation (your own link) that the `FROM` must include just one table...

Comment: That seems like old documentation. The inner join examples show different tables are being joined: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views#supported_query_rewrite_patterns_2

Comment: The Limitations section says "Must be aggregated...", but there is no aggregation here.

Comment: As of 4 days ago joins in materialised views are generally available and the requirement that they must be aggregated has gone away https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#January_31_2022